# Compilation error in method call

Tags: java

```
class Persons {
    private String name;

    public Persons(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equal(Persons p) {
        return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }

}

public class pa {
    public static void main(String ar[]) {
        Persons a = new Persons("Roman");
        boolean max;
        max = a.equal(new Persons());
        System.out.print(max);
    }

}
```

Comment: Want to give a hint as to the error message?

Comment: Some introductory text would be welcomed

Answer (score 2):

you do **not** have default constructor in your `Persons` class

change

```
    max = a.equal(new Persons());
```

to

```
    max = a.equal(new Persons("someValue"));
```

or provide default constructor

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 constructor in class `Person`

```
public Persons(String name) {
        this.name = name;
}
```

But, you create a new instance of `Person` like this:

```
max = a.equal(new Persons());
```

Solutions:

1. Create a default constructor : `public Persons () { }`
2. Use existing constructor : `max = a.equal(new Persons(""));`

Answer (score 0):

Always add a default constructor when providing a parametrized one.

```
class Persons {
    private String name;

    public Persons(){
    } 

    public Persons(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean equal(Persons p) {
        return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a default constructor for Person,

```
 max = a.equal(new Persons("")); // <-- need a String.
```

Also, you should name your method `equals()`, because that's the Object method;

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object p) {
  if (p instanceof Persons) {
    return this.name.equals(((Persons) p).name);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also you do not have constructor like this :

```
public Persons() //no parameter
 {
        this.name = name;
 }
```

so you can't create a new instance of `Persons` (wow! too many person.)  using the above constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here

```
 Persons a = new Persons("Roman");
 boolean max;
 max = a.equal(new Persons()); // Persons class don't have no-argument construtor
```

You have to change this to

```
max = a.equal(new Persons("yourValue"));
```

Or you can add no argument constructor to `Persons` class.

```
public Persons(){

}
```